# Syntax of rqt_graph filters

Tags: ros, nodes, rqt-graph, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently noticed, that you can use a wildcard character in rqt_graph to select node or topic names. For example "/imu*" would only show all nodes/topics which start with "/imu".
Is there a way to logically link multiple filter expressions together, e.g. "Show all nodes, which start with '/imu' or '/move'"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280233/syntax-of-rqt_graph-filters/) by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 775 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the tooltip [and the code for that](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/3d77bb80bfd8df4b4849f35ec4edfda09e750943/resource/RosGraph.ui#L58-L64), the filter edit boxes accept a comma separated list of regexps:

> ```
> Topic filter, comma separated list of names/regexp to include or exclude. Example: -/tf
> ```

So the regexp could have optional and required matches as well.

Doesn't seem to be documented too well, but [this comment](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/issues/4#issuecomment-296804076) on issue 4 of the `rqt_graph` issue tracker has an example:

> You can add filter, some sort of: `-(._parameter_updates),-(._parameter_descriptions)`

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on 2018-01-25**:
Thank you! This works.